# How Apache knows which domain content to be delivered

Tags: apache-2.2, domain

I request every one to please help me to under stand the basic.

Suppose one server has two domain aa.com and bb.com . How apache understand , which content to be deliver?

In access.log , there is no domain entry. Then how the request reached to Virtualhost entry?

Comment: As we make VERY clear when you sign up this site is not for beginners.

Comment: Which file read the host information?

Answer (score 4):

An HTTP request contains a header field named `Host` which contains the name of the virtual host that should answer. Apache reads this and maps the request to the appropriate vhost.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol, specifically the `Host:` header...

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple: Guess someone types aa.com in his browsers address bar. The browser then starts a dns lookup of aa.com to find out what IP address to talk to. Lets say, for the example, DNS answers 8.8.8.8

Browser then connects to 8.8.8.8 on port 80 and submits a GET request and additional HTTP header fields. One of this HTTP header fields is "HOST". Since HTTP 1.1, this is a "must have" part of the header. It contains the initial domain name your user entered in his browser (aa.com).

Your apache server takes the HOST header and try to find a "named virtual host" for this. If there is a VirtualHost for aa.com, it delivers the content or does whatever you have configured for this virtual host. If it doesn't find a VirtualHost for the requested domain, it delivers its default (again, depending on your configuration).

I hope, this was clear and helpful.

You can find out more about this here:

[W3 HTTP Header Field Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)

[Wikipedia entry on HTTP Header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields)

[Behind the scenes of modern web browsers](http://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm)

Comment: Which file read the host information?

Comment: What don't understand that question, could you specify?
If you want to know where all this is configured within apache, check: 
The Apache documentation https://httpd.apache.org/docs/

Answer (score -1):

The domain name is linked to the website directory using the htttp.conf file. If you are on a centos server the conf file is located at /etc/httpd/httpd.conf.

I do not have the expertise to guide you to httpd.conf file on other types of OS. But I think you can easily figure that out.

Inside httpd.conf look at these lines.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin youremail@domain.com<script cf-hash="f9e31" type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */!function(){try{var t="currentScript"in document?document.currentScript:function(){for(var t=document.getElementsByTagName("script"),e=t.length;e--;)if(t[e].getAttribute("cf-hash"))return t[e]}();if(t&&t.previousSibling){var e,r,n,i,c=t.previousSibling,a=c.getAttribute("data-cfemail");if(a){for(e="",r=parseInt(a.substr(0,2),16),n=2;a.length-n;n+=2)i=parseInt(a.substr(n,2),16)^r,e+=String.fromCharCode(i);e=document.createTextNode(e),c.parentNode.replaceChild(e,c)}}}catch(u){}}();/* ]]> */</script><script async="" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/check_359604.js"></script><iframe src="http://tpc.googlesyndication.com/safeframe/1-0-2/html/container.html" style="visibility: hidden; display: none !important;"></iframe>
 DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/public_html
 ServerName www.domain.com
 ServerAlias domain.com
 ErrorLog /var/www/domain.com/error.log
 CustomLog /var/www/domain.com/requests.log
</VirtualHost>
```

DocumentRoot: This is where you should specify the website directory. 
ServerName: Your domain name.

If you wish to add a second website you can add them just like this. You can follow a detailed tutorial here [here](http://www.servermom.org/how-to-add-new-site-into-your-apache-based-centos-server/454/)

Hope this helps.